# Llamar función JAVASCRIPT desde HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Éste es el código de la vista:

```js
function  CodigoValidacion(pala) {
 
 var fraseUser=pala.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g,"");

 fraserReverse=fraseUser.split("").reverse().toString();

 for (var i = 0; i < ((fraserReverse.length)-1); i++) {
  fraserReverse=fraserReverse.replace(",","");
 };

 if(fraseUser==fraserReverse){
  pala.setCustomValidity("Polindromo Confirmado");
  pala.value="";
 } else{
  pala.setCustomValidity("No es Polindromo");
  pala.value="";
  return false;
 }
}
```

```html
<h1>Validar Palindromo</h1>
<form>
 <label>Palabra/Frase:</label>
 <input type="text" id="pala" name="pala">
 <button type="submit" 
         onclick="CodigoValidacion(pala)">
   Ingresar
 </button>
</form>
```

Ahora no recibo respuesta, no logro encontrar la falla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te falto pala.value para obtener el valor del elemento.

var fraseUser=pala.toLowerCase()....
var fraseUser=pala.value.toLowerCase()....

```js
function  CodigoValidacion(pala) {
 
 var fraseUser=pala.value.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g,"");

 fraserReverse=fraseUser.split("").reverse().toString();

 for (var i = 0; i < ((fraserReverse.length)-1); i++) {
  fraserReverse=fraserReverse.replace(",","");
 };

 if(fraseUser==fraserReverse){
  pala.setCustomValidity("Polindromo Confirmado");
  pala.value="";
 } else{
  pala.setCustomValidity("No es Polindromo");
  pala.value="";
  return false;
 }
}
```

```html
<h1>Validar Palindromo</h1>
<form>
 <label>Palabra/Frase:</label>
 <input type="text" id="pala" name="pala">
 <button type="submit" 
         onclick="CodigoValidacion(pala)">
   Ingresar
 </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenías un pequeño error:

- Para obtener la frase del usuario hacias: `pala.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g,"");` lo cual no tiene sentido porque `pala` es un elemento, no es el valor del input. Es posible acceder al atributo `value` del elemento para obtenerlo como texto.

```js
function  CodigoValidacion(pala) {
 var fraseUser=pala.value.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g,"");

 fraserReverse=fraseUser.split("").reverse().toString();

 for (var i = 0; i < ((fraserReverse.length)-1); i++) {
    fraserReverse=fraserReverse.replace(",","");
  };

  if(fraseUser==fraserReverse){
    pala.setCustomValidity("Polindromo Confirmado");
    pala.value="";

  } else{
    pala.setCustomValidity("No es Polindromo");
    pala.value="";
    return false;
    }
  }
```

```html
<h1>Validar Palindromo</h1>
 <form>
  <label>Palabra/Frase:</label>
  <input type="text" id="pala" name="pala">
  <button type="submit" onclick="CodigoValidacion(pala)">Ingresar</button>
 </form>
```